# Google Colab - how to compare two photos

Tags: python

How can I compare two photos?
I am using two images one of a healthy lung and one that isn't.
I want to be able in some way create a way so that code can compare the two photos. maybe try to have the code store in memory what a healthy lung looks like so when the user uploads the same photo of a heathy lung vs a unhealthy one the code will be able to distinguish between the two and say which one is the healthy one and which isn't

this is what i have so far:

```
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2
```

```
# using files upload, we upload the photo from laptop. 
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
# the photo below is a MRI of a healthy lung 
img = cv2.imread('./download-1.jpg')

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

```
# the photo below is a MRI of a unhealthy lung 
img2 = cv2.imread('./download.jpg')

plt.imshow(img2)
plt.show()`
```

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What are you actually looking is not a image comparison per se, but training a model with healthy images and unhealthy images. The ML algorithm should be trained with many pictures of both categories. I would start using AutoML Vision from Google cloud and label your images: Lets say 100 healthy lungs and 100 unhealthy lungs. Then you will predict passing new images and AutoML should help you get the right category. https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/beginners-guide

Comment: @jakub, maybe try to have the code store in memory what a healthy lung looks like so when the user uploads the same photo of a heathy lung vs a unhealthy one the code will be able to distinguish bewteen the two and say which one is the healthy one and which isnt

Comment: @elishua - it sounds like you are trying to solve a computer vision problem. As gogasca wrote in their comment, you could use machine learning / deep learning for this problem. The learning curve can be steep, and lots of data are required. To get a practical idea of what I am talking about, take a look at the [TensorFlow Keras image classification tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification). They show you how you can classify types of clothing, and you can extend those concepts to healthy vs unhealthy lungs.